# Displaying image sequence in Qt GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qtgui, qt-signals

I have an OpenCV algorithm that processes an image sequence, and I want to display each processed frame in the Qt window using code like this:

```
while(someCondition){
    Mat img;
    ... //some OpenCV process here
    QImage qimg = matToQImage (img); //a function I found
    ui->someLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimg));

    //I want to add a delay here or some wait condition
}
```

But only the last image is displayed in the label. I think it's because the loop is too fast and the GUI can't update it fast enough. Is there a way I can make the loop pause to give the GUI time to show the image, and then continue only when the GUI has displayed the image?

Comment: Why are you trying to update it so often if the image comes faster than the UI update? Why are you just not dropping loop concept in favor of signals and slots, like a QTimer or reimplementing paintEvent in a widget subclass with drawImage() and own signal emission?

Comment: I was thinking I could do something like when using only OpenCV where I can just call `cv::imshow()` and then `cvWaitKey()` in each iteration. I've just actually rewrote the loop as a QTimer slot and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply to my comment question, this seems to be an acceptable solution for you:

```
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=] () {
        Mat img;
        ... //some OpenCV process here
        QImage qimg = matToQImage (img); //a function I found
        ui->someLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimg));
    });
    timer->start(10);
```

Since it is using [the new shiny signal-slot syntax for syntactic sugar](http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html), do not forget to add this to your project file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```